# open ad banner (detail) view in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, storyboard, iad

I am developing an app in landscape mode. For the same, I had placed the iAd Banner in landscape mode. And it is working fine too. But I got the issue when I tried to see its detail page it is opening in portrait mode. I search on Google but didn't get any solution to view the iAd detail page in landscape mode. If someone has any idea please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`From Apple Docs,`

Any user interface screen that includes a banner view must be managed by a view controller (a class that subclasses UIViewController).

This allows a triggered action to cover your user interface with an additional advertising screen. Whenever a banner view is visible, it must be part of a view hierarchy that is attached to the view property of a view controller.

**Your second view controller should be the child of the Main View controller.**

For More details Please Refer [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html)

Comment: Can you send any example?

Comment: @Sudha http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_iAds_into_an_iOS_5_iPad_App http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/iad-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app check here